# Moving folders inside of folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, shutil

I have folders named from `00` to `ff` (all lower-cased) that have a random number of folders inside them named randomly as well. I need to only move the folders inside to a different location.

```
folders = list((range(256)))
for i in range(256):
    folders[i] = hex(folders[i])[2:4]
    if len(folders[i]) == 1:
        folders[i] = "0" + folders[i]
for i in range(len(folders)):
    shutil.move(f"D:\folders\{folders[i]\*}", "D:\MainFolder")
```

I am expecting all the files inside `D:\folders\(00)` to move into `D:\Mainfolder` and to repeat until all the files are moved in but it's throwing an error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'D:\\folders\\00\\*'
```

Also, was there any way to improve the way I made the array?

Comment: Isn't this the explicit folder path? it does identify the 00 with autocompletion when I am typing so I thought this was fine only the star seems to cause the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`shutil.move`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) is expecting to get an explicit path as an argument. It seems that you are confusing with [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) that can take the path with shell-like wildcards. I am assuming that with the `*` you mean to move anything under that folder, but that is not necessary. As [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) state:

> ***Recursively*** move a file or directory (src) to another location (dst)

(emphasis mine).

---

As a side note, you can obtain the `folders` list much easier, by using [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/#string_pad_align):

```
folders = [f"{hex(i)[2:]:0>2}" for i in range(256)]
```

Or simply avoid saving such a list in memory and just do:

```py
for i in range(256):
    shutil.move(f"D:\folders\{hex(i)[2:]:0>2}", "D:\MainFolder")
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix your command as:
`shutil.move(f"D:\folders\{folders[i]}\*","D:\MainFolder")`

Comment: I fixed that but still throwing an error, I guess it can't identify the ' * '?